# openerp: how i can add function on date field to send notification

Tags: python, date, odoo

I create a new openerp object to monitor the insurance issuance of employee dependants the python code:

class hr_emp_dependents(osv.osv):

```
_name = 'hr.emp.dependents'
_description = 'HR Employee Dependents Line'
_columns = {
    'emp_line': fields.many2one('hr.employee', 'Employee', readonly=False),
    'nationality':fields.many2one('res.country', 'Nationality', required=True),
    'name': fields.char('Name', size=50, readonly=False, required=True),
    'gender': fields.selection([('male', 'Male'),('female', 'Female')], 'Gender', required=True),
    'birthplace': fields.many2one('res.country', 'Birth Place', required=True),
    'relation': fields.many2one('hr.relation', 'Relation', required=True, domain="[('gender','=',gender)]"),
    'dob': fields.date('Date of Birth', required=False),
    'identification_id':fields.char('Identification No', required=False, help="Dependent's ID Information"),
    'insurance_no': fields.char('Medical Insurance No', size=10, required=False),
    'insurance_start_date': fields.date('Insurance Start Date', size=10, required=False),
    'insurance_exp_date': fields.date('Insurance Expire Date', size=10, required=False),
}
```

hr_emp_dependents()

I need to add function to automatically return the current date and if 'insurance_exp_date' is less by 5 than current date send notification to all users on HR/manger group how I can do that??

Comment: 1.) Don't beg for help. 2.) Correct syntax? In what language? Do you want a date in a specific format? 3.) This question is incomplete and shows no effort in solving it yourself. Every major language can handle date logic and formatting and how to do so is as simple as reading the manual. So, if you want help, you need put more effort into this question at the very least.

Comment: hope that's clear now

Answer (score 0):

To sent notification mails, its better to create a cron job(scheduler).Go to settings/technical/scheduler/scheduler actions. In that create a new scheduler action. In the extra tab specify the function name you want to execute. Check any of the scheduler actions.

Comment: how can i fix    record[f] = res2[record['id']]
KeyError: 1